# getting arraylist size as ZERO while getting data from server?

Tags: android

I am trying to show data on daynamic list view. I get data from server database. but the problem in my code is task_kist is a string type arraylist. As I execute

```
new TaskList().execute();
```

before

```
Log.i("Total size", String.valueOf(task_list.size()));
```

this line execute before "new TaskList().execute();" . In class TaskList the size or task_list is 11 but when i check total size as mentioned above, it is 0. Can anyone please suggest me the solution that why size of task_list is zero while I added some values in it.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tasklist);

     Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        username = bundle.getString("username");

        Log.i("username from login", username);

        registerButtons();

        new TaskList().execute();
        Log.i("Totalllllll size", String.valueOf(task_list.size()));



        String str[] = new String[5];

        for(int i =0; i<5;i++) {
            str[i]=String.valueOf(task_list.size());
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> ap = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.test_list_item,str);
        lv.setAdapter(ap);


        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {


                Toast.makeText(AllTask.this, "You have Selected : "+((TextView)arg1).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


  }
 /**
 * Background Async Task to Create new product
 * */
class TaskList extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Creating product
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));


        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_get_tasklist,
                "GET", params);

        // check log cat fro response
        Log.i("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);


            if (success == 1) {


                tasks = json.getJSONArray(TAG_NAME);

                // looping through All members
                for (int i = 0; i < tasks.length(); i++) {


                    JSONObject c = tasks.getJSONObject(i);


                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    tasklist = c.getString(TAG_TASKLIST);



                    task_list.add(tasklist);
                    Log.i("size", String.valueOf(task_list.size()));
                    Log.i("array", task_list.get(i));


                }


            } else {

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }


}
```

Comment: is TaskList an inner class?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are getting size in async task which run in background thread.And before completing the async task your log print value as 0 
So track log in `doInBackground` `for` loop as

```
// looping through All members
                for (int i = 0; i < tasks.length(); i++) {
//your code 
}
Log.i("Total size", String.valueOf(task_list.size()));  // track log here
```

**Edit**
Also you may track log `onPostExecute` in method as

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Log.i("Total size", String.valueOf(task_list.size()));  // track log here
}
```

Comment: but I need task_list size after background process end for popolating it in listview. what should I do?

Comment: @Farah you may track log in onPostExecute method. see Edit section in answer.

Comment: ok I got the right size. but this size and task_list values I have to copy them in String str. what should I do that it wait for the postExecute method to be complete?

Comment: You can implement all the functionality which you want,in onpostexecute method. Because on post execute method call automatically after doinbackground

Comment: I tried but It shows error while I copy the code in that method.

     String str[] = new String[5];

        for(int i =0; i<5;i++) {
            str[i]=String.valueOf(task_list.size());
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> ap = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.test_list_item,str);
        lv.setAdapter(ap);